# Vim path separator & auto-completion

Tags: vim, path, autocomplete

Working on web stuff, in windows, to be hosted on linux.

Completing paths with ^X^F automatically inserts "\" as the path separator on windows, which is quite correct, but not what I want, so:

Is there a way I can tell it to use "/" as the path separator for auto-completion regardless of OS?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps this helps, or is at least a starting point for further digging:

`:help dos-backslash`

shows

> *When you prefer to use forward slashes, set the 'shellslash' option.  Vim will
>     then replace backslashes with forward slashes when expanding file names.  This
>     is especially useful when using a Unix-like 'shell'.*

Comment: Winner!

I am dropping its shortcut "set ssl" in certain ftplugin files now

Comment: `:set ssl` -> slashes will be forward slashes  `/`  (ssl is short for shellslash)
`:set nossl` -> slashes will be backward slashes  `\\`